# fetch integer value in XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt-3.0

I have a json input, it has both interger and string values.

```
{
"name":"jj",
"id":123
}
```

I'm performing json to json conversion.

using map I'm representing in key and value format.

```
<string key="name1">
<xsl:value-of select='$data//string[@key="name"]'/>
</string>
<string key="id1">
<xsl:value-of select='$data//string[@key="id"]'/>
</string>
```

when i try to fetch integer values its giving indouble quotes.

output:-

```
{
"name1":"jjj",
"id1":""
}
```

expected output:-

```
{
"name1":"jj",
"id1":123
}
```

Thank you.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON only has a single number type, double, represented for `xml-to-json` or `json-to-xml` in XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 by the `number` element, not the `string` element. Thus use `<number key="id1">...</number>` on the XML side to end up with a numeric value in JSON.